# Angular project(dist folder) deployment in Websphere Application server

Tags: angular

can any one provide the steps to deploy the Angular "ng build" command generated /dist folder in IBM Websphere application server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Asking a question on SO should not be the first step in the process for finding an answer - if the information that you need already exists online, then you should want to find it yourself.  After researching yourself, you will have the necessary information to post precise questions when you are stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I use it at work but i don't really know the configuration of the server.
On the application side you can do the following:

### Manual method

1. **Compile** in production mode
2. Create a folder **WEB-INF**: in this folder configure a **web.xml** with the
   information you need (in my case datasources, basic authentication
   and http operations allowed)
3. Create a folder **META-INF** containing a manifest.MF (bretty much
   useless for me) and a **context.xml** containing only the context path
   of the application
4. Put theese folders alongside the compiled code
5. Now create a .war file: i use a terminal command like this:

   `jar -cvf yourProject.war -C C:\...\yourProject\dist\yourProject .` 
   Basically it means: take all the files inside the specified path (the dot is important) and create a war with them.

### IDE method

I use NetBeans because with an IDE is all more confortable. The main difference is that **you don't launch the `jar -cvf` manually**, but you simply build the project, and depending which ide you're using the *context.xml*, the *manifest.mf* and the *web.xml* might be already there.

Before that you want to copy the **compiled code** into the **Web Pages folder**, then I build the project.

---

Finally I install the application using the IBM console.
Hope this works for you!

**P.S.**
This method is a little bit clunky, maybe there is a better one...